# Why is my flask server socketio connect event being called each time a message is emitted?

Tags: reactjs, flask, socket.io

I currently have a React component that will connect to a web socket and print out the data received line by line. On the server side, my Flask app will start a background thread to emit a test message every 3 seconds.

Each time the server emits a message, the connect() event looks like it gets called. Is this expected? Or could it be related to the React component?

**React component**

```
const OutputWindow: React.FC = () => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
    const [socketData, setSocketData] = useState<string[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connect established');
        })

        socket.on('server_data', (data) => {
            console.log('Receved data from server! ' + data);
            setSocketData(prevSocketData => [...prevSocketData, data]);
        })
    }, []);

    return (
            <div className="window"> 
            {socketData.map((line, index) => (
                <p className="log-line" key={index}>
                    {line}
                </p>
            ))}
            </div>
    );
};
```

Flask server that emits a test message every 3 seconds

```
log_thread=None
thread_lock = threading.Lock()

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print(f'Client connected')

    # Start thread that will emit log file data
    global log_thread
    with thread_lock:
        if log_thread is None:
            log_thread = socketio.start_background_task(send_data)


@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print(f'A client disconnected')


def send_data():
    print("Streaming thread started.")

    while True:
        socketio.emit("server_data", "test message")
        socketio.sleep(3)
```

**Server side logs:**

```
Client connected
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:44] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj3O8&sid=IQl7g7aZKld0tgYmAABc HTTP/1.1" 200 223 0.002163
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:44] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj3O9&sid=IQl7g7aZKld0tgYmAABc HTTP/1.1" 200 269 0.000791
(11137) accepted ('192.168.0.163', 53459)
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:44] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj3OM&sid=IQl7g7aZKld0tgYmAABc HTTP/1.1" 200 237 0.000521
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:47] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj46N HTTP/1.1" 200 334 0.002502
Client connected
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:47] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj46n&sid=yvHGCciJ0W7xnNnAAABe HTTP/1.1" 200 223 0.003354
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:47] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj46o&sid=yvHGCciJ0W7xnNnAAABe HTTP/1.1" 200 269 0.001139
(11137) accepted ('192.168.0.163', 53469)
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:47] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj470&sid=yvHGCciJ0W7xnNnAAABe HTTP/1.1" 200 237 0.000995
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:47] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj478&sid=yvHGCciJ0W7xnNnAAABe HTTP/1.1" 200 237 0.000471
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:50] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj4rG HTTP/1.1" 200 334 0.002346
Client connected
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:50] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj4re&sid=whjNXNF1fxP0ALzoAABg HTTP/1.1" 200 223 0.003343
(11137) accepted ('192.168.0.163', 53483)
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:50] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj4rf&sid=whjNXNF1fxP0ALzoAABg HTTP/1.1" 200 269 0.001593
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:50] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj4rt&sid=whjNXNF1fxP0ALzoAABg HTTP/1.1" 200 237 0.000644
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:50] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj4r_&sid=whjNXNF1fxP0ALzoAABg HTTP/1.1" 200 237 0.000649
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:53] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj5aB HTTP/1.1" 200 334 0.001117
Client connected
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:53] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj5aP&sid=h-X6Aw4YsFBTn2HfAABi HTTP/1.1" 200 223 0.001594
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:53] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj5aP.0&sid=h-X6Aw4YsFBTn2HfAABi HTTP/1.1" 200 269 0.000485
(11137) accepted ('192.168.0.163', 53517)
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:53] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj5ab&sid=h-X6Aw4YsFBTn2HfAABi HTTP/1.1" 200 237 0.000454
192.168.0.163 - - [08/Aug/2023 15:11:53] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdLj5ai&sid=h-X6Aw4YsFBTn2HfAABi HTTP/1.1" 200 237 0.000449
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be because your components gets re-rendered since you update your `socketData` state, and then a new connection gets opened `const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');`

I will personally make sure this connection is made once, using `useMemo`

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
.
.
.

const socket = useMemo(() => {
    return io('http://localhost:5000');
}, []);
```

https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo

Another way is to create a Context API and for the first time the component gets render, you store in a state the connection returned from `io()` and then you can use the connection in other components.

```
// Context API
    
import {createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
// other impots

export const SocketContext = createContext();

export function useSocket() {
  return useContext(SocketContext);
}

export default function SocketProvider({ children }) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const connection = io('....');
    setSocket(connection);
  }, []); // make sure the connection is first made on the first render

  return <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket }}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>
}

// add to App.jsx or index.jsx

// import SocketProvider from ...
// import MyComponent from ...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SocketProvider>
        <MyComponent />
      <SocketProvider>
    </div>
  );
}



// usage:

export function MyComponent() {
  const { socket } = useSocket();
  // ... your states

  useEffect(() => {
      /*
        ... your code ...

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connect established');
        })

        socket.on('server_data', (data) => {
            console.log('Receved data from server! ' + data);
            setSocketData(prevSocketData => [...prevSocketData, data]);
        })
      */
  }, [socket]); // since connection was made and `socket` state changed, it will contain the connection and this useEffect will be called only once, since `socket` state will change only 1 time (on first rendered in the context api component)

  return /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I suspected it was related to the rerendering. I did not know about `useMemo`. Thank you!